# Laplace Transformation-Unit Step Function

Tags: laplace-transform

[image]

I need to do a laplace transformation to the following function. Every time I tried I got the wrong answer. Do I do laplace transformation separately to the part that is inside the brackets, and to the part that is outside the brackets?
This is what I did:
[image]

Comment: Please use MathJax https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @noamAzulay: $$6 \left(\dfrac{e^{-\pi  s} (s+4)}{(s+4)^2+1}-\dfrac{e^{-\pi  s}}{s}+\dfrac{1}{s}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I understand my mistake...